# How to write Series data into a file

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am writing data into a file. A part of the code involves writing a Series into the file. I know how to simply write the Series to a file by using `to_csv`, but what I am doing here is writing a bunch of lines and then I want to display the content of the Series. I haven't figured out how to do it.

I tried simply doing something like:

```
fileWrite= open("details.txt", "w")

fileWrite.write("This report is for todays data \n\n")
fileWrite.write("Please see the breakdown based on items sold \n\n")

fileWrite.write(df_fridge_grp)
```

This is my data series:

```
fields = ['Date', 'Name', 'SoldItem']
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
df_fridge = df.loc[(df['SoldItem'] == 'Fridge')]
df_fridge_grp = df_fridge.groupby(["Date", "Name"]).size()
```

This is my DataFrame:

```
Dataframe is
Date     Name    SoldItem
15-Jul    Joe     TV
15-Jul    Joe     Fridge
15-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine
15-Jul    Joe     TV
15-Jul    Joe     Fridge
15-Jul    Mary    Chair
15-Jul    Mary    Fridge
16-Jul    Joe     Fridge
16-Jul    Joe     Fridge
16-Jul    Tim     Washing Machine
17-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine
17-Jul    Jimmy   Washing Machine
17-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine
17-Jul    Joe     Washing Machine
```

The output just prints the series name rather than the actual contents:

```
This report is for todays data
Please see the breakdown based on items sold
df_fridge_grp
```

Instead of:

```
This report is for todays data
Please see the breakdown based on items sold
Date      Name   Count
15-Jul     Joe       2
          Mary       1
16-Jul     Joe       2
```

Comment: When you write the dataframe to the file do you want it look how you have it here? With spaces (instead of how to_csv would write it with commas)?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do something with to_string()

```
print(df_fridge_grp.to_string())
```

or for your use-case:

```
fileWrite.write(df_fridge_grp.to_string())
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
fileWrite.write(df_fridge_grp)
```

is not what you ran to get that output or you would have gotten `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not DataFrame`. You probably did:

```
fileWrite.write("df_fridge_grp")
```

This is not going to store the dataframe as that is just a string. The correct way to do it is by getting a string representation of the dataframe and storing that. You can do that like this:

```
fileWrite.write(str(df_fridge_grp))
fileWrite.close()
```

And always make sure to close your file!

Comment: You should explain a little more your answer. Just from this, it's really hard to tell how or why your answer works.

Comment: @ifconfig fair enough. Added an explanation